# Programmatic use of cmd.exe from C#

Tags: c#, command-line, process

1. I want to run a series of commands on cmd.exe from C#.
2. I need to open only one window of cmd
3. I need to keep the cmd window open through the execution and after the completion.
4. I need to display the commands **[edit]in the opened cmd window[/edit]** executed as well as the output of the commands.

So basically I want to open and use the cmd.exe just like a manual user would.
I tried some methods, but none could do all 4 items above.

Below code works but does not display the commands/outputs and terminates after completion.
Any help?

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
info.Arguments = "/k";

p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
         sw.WriteLine("dir");
         sw.WriteLine("ipconfig");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works and displays commands/outputs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RedirectStandard...`-properties are misleading. As soon as you set one of them, all three streams will be redirected. This is because the underlying Windows API only has a single flag to control redirection - `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`.

Because you didn't set the `RedirectStandardOutput` property to true, the stdout streams isn't made available to your code, but instead will be redirected to the `Console.Out` stream of your own process.
Thus, your code works fine as long as the parent process is a console application; but in a Windows application, the output gets redirected into nothingness.

An easy workaround is to temporarily turn your parent process into a console application:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.CreateNoWindow = false;

    p.StartInfo = info;
    AllocConsole();
    p.Start();
    FreeConsole();


    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
             sw.WriteLine("dir");
             sw.WriteLine("ipconfig");
        }
    }
}
```

As for keeping the console open: you could just remove the `FreeConsole()` call so that the parent process keeps the console around even after cmd.exe exits. However this may be a problem if you need multiple consoles, as your parent process can't be associated with more than one console at a time.

Alternatively, don't close the input stream so that cmd.exe keeps running.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, i was wondering why the output was redirected to console while debugging even when i did not set the RedirectStandardOutput to true. Your code does pretty much what i need visually. However there are 2 limitations.  1- I can only open one console which you pointed out.  2 - If i close the console, the application terminates which i do not want.  Would it be possible to create a child process and run the console from that one so it would be an independent console or do child processes share the console?

Comment: Those two problems don't occur if you call `FreeConsole()`. In that case, you'll have to keep the input stream open (no `using` block) so that cmd.exe keeps running.

Comment: I did try that but it just resulted in the console hanging without doing anything.  When i tried it the release build it works like a charm though:) Still it works so thanks

Answer (score 0):

For seeing the out put insert `Console.ReadLine();`(application stop until you send a key so you can see the result) after command executed.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.CreateNoWindow = false;

                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();

                using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
                {
                    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("dir");

                        sw.WriteLine("ipconfig");
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks IRSOG but, I need both the commands and the output displayed on the opened cmd window not just read it into memory