# WPF cmd.exe Process closes immediatly

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I am trying to open cmd.exe through System.Diagnostics.Process but every time it hits process.Start() it closes immediately and I cannot write anything else to it.  However if I call the static Process.Start() it will stay open but then I am unsure how to write to it. See below.

```
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
        };

        var process = new Process()
        {
           StartInfo = processInfo,
        };

        process.Start(); // This close immediately and not work 

        Process.Start("cmd.exe"); // This will work but can't write to it

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(someText);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(moreText);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Answer (score 1):

Use to wait for cmd.

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: inserting this line of code still does not make the code work.

Comment: Does the app still close immediately for you?

Comment: Yes, It does close immediately.

Comment: Could you post some code as to what you are trying to do.. ideally this statement should wait for your process (here cmd) to close before exiting.

Comment: I used the same code as OP posted and incorporated your suggested change, that's all.

Comment: See if any of the other answers help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-until-a-process-ends?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found the solution implemented [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945398/2843342) works. Not sure if this is the best approach, but it worked for me.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

private void BtnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true
        };

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = processInfo,
        };

        AllocConsole();
        process.Start(); // This close immediately and not work 

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("someText");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("moreText");
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: So this works well on my Windows 7 laptop but in Windows 10 it does stay up but the directories are blank and whatever I write to it does not show up.

Comment: Btw - I don't know if this was obvious or not but I did not know. This is only an issue when debugging in Visual Studio. Once you deploy your project and it runs on the .exe file the command prompt window stays up and you can write to it no problem!